# NUMA - Local memory

Tags: windows, processor, numa

Please bear with me, I've just started digging into this whole CPU thing.

The `RAM` squares shown on the diagram below, what do they refer to? Memory pages? As far as I know, CPUs only have one thing that's related to memory at all - their cache.

So is the `RAM` on the diagram just a shared cache, or what is it?

[image: NUMA Architecture Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that diagram, each group of 4 CPUs and their central RAM block is a NUMA node. Cache is inside each CPU so it's not shown in the diagram. So each group of 4 CPUs share a block of fast local RAM.

Within each node, memory access to local RAM is very fast. Remote access to another node needs to go through the communication network, therefore it is slower - hence NUMA.

Comment: Local RAM? Since when did CPUs get RAM?! Or is it the main memory that's splitted into chunks, and then called "local memory"?

Comment: It's main memory split into chunks. Each group of 4 CPUs has only a part of the main memory. That part is the local memory.

Comment: @Mystical, Ah - that makes so much more sense! - I thought for a moment that each CPU had some memory, and when used in a NUMA architecture they shared their respective memory. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: Yeah, a typical 4-socket server motherboard will have 4 nodes - one for each (multi-core) CPU. Each node has a CPU and it's own memory bank. When you boot it up, the total system memory is the total memory in the machine. So any program can access all the memory regardless of where it is. But since some memory regions are faster depending on whether it's local to the core that's accessing it, it is NUMA.

Comment: Thanks :) Didn't know that sockets on the motherboard equals number of nodes. Also just to be 100% sure: with memory bank you meant the chunk of memory from the main memory right?

Comment: It isn't *always* equal to the number of nodes - but it *usually* is. By "banks", yes, it's each chunk of memory. If you look at a picture of a 4-socket AMD motherboard, it's very obvious. Each CPU socket has a few ram slots right next to it. (http://www.tyan.com/product_board_detail.aspx?pid=271)

Comment: Another awesome thing I didn't know! - In order to figure out whether a motherboard is using NUMA or SMP architechture, you can simply look at how the ram slots are placed?

Comment: For the most part yes, this is a pretty reliable way (though not a guarantee). I actually have yet to see any counter-examples.